# vbs custom font in Word Application

Tags: vbscript, fonts, custom-font

I'm doing script that will add custom signature in Outlook. I cannot find how to add custom font to `objWord.Selection` for example:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Selection.fontPath "C://...../customFont.ttf"
objSelection.TypeText "some text example"
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to set font size, style and type. Note that you can change font for a selected text from a word doc. (You can select text by using Range(). )

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection  
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()

objRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
objRange.Font.Size = 12
objRange.Font.Bold= True
```

See documentation for other properties of Font Object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/font-object-word

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/font-object-excel

Notes:

- `Set objSelection = objWord.Selection` creates a Selection Object at the start of the document - this is used for inserting text, it is not necessary for Font selection.
- `Set objRange = objDoc.Range()` selects the whole document. 
  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-range-method-word for adding parameters for Range method

Comment: thanks for that, but I wounder if I can import my font from some external location? I have .ttf font file..

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer.

Comment: @ Jure Možina: Maybe if you have previously installed your font. https://www.wikihow.com/Add-Font-in-Microsoft-Word

Comment: this is not fine solution coz' I am doing this script for users in company, so for example; if some would need his it's own signature, will just run this file, so this font needs to be integrated in script, or maybe if is vbs command to install custom font?